# How display a bucle for 'post' in a booststrap carousel?

Tags: django, python-3.x, html

I'm new to django and i'm doing my first project.

my question is how display my posts in a bootstrap carrousel?

I used: Boostrap 4.3.1
        Django 2.2

this is my code:

base.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>
     ...
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

post_list.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<br>
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="date">
            <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
        </div>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>    </h1>
        <h5 class="badge badge-secondary">by {{ post.author }}</h5>
        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">Comments: {{     post.comments.count }}</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(
        blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.publish_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

and views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def post_list(request):
    posts =Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    posts = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': posts})
```

I tried with this code but it doesn´t work:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
{% for post in posts|slice:":3" %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
        <div class="active item">
    {% else %}
        <div class="item">
   {% endif %}
        <blockquote>
            <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
        </blockquote>
        <label>{{ post.text }}</label>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

I want it to look like this without the img:

[image]

My template looks now:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide your views.py so we can see what's going on

Comment: i edit the post :)

Comment: How are you accessing your view? Can you post your urls.py here? Also, what can you see in your template?

Comment: update @HigorRossato

Comment: Please correct me if I’m won’t but it seems your issue is more related to styling/css and not so much with Django because I can see the posts on the page although they’re not styled the way you want. Is that correct?! If so try to check the browser console to see what’s happening.